# Stripe react native override intentCreationCallback in payment sheet

Tags: swift, react-native, stripe-payments

This is challenging. I've spent days looking at the code and still haven't found a way to automatically return a `success` in `intentCreationCallback` from [stripe-react-native](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native).

I run something like:

```js
initPaymentSheet({
  customerId: user?.stripe?.customer,
  customerEphemeralKeySecret: ephemeralKey,
  intentConfiguration: {
    mode: {
      amount,
      currencyCode: 'USD',
    },
    confirmHandler,
  },
})

const confirmHandler: IntentConfiguration['confirmHandler'] = async (
  paymentMethod,
  shouldSavePaymentMethod,
  intentCreationCallback
) => {
  try {
    ...
    // Clone the paymentMethod on our server, create a paymentIntent and return a clientSecret
    const { clientSecret } = await GQL_stripeHandleConfirm({
      variables: {...},
    });
    intentCreationCallback({ clientSecret });
};
```

`GQL_stripeHandleConfirm` runs a function on our graphQL server which clones the `paymentMethod` passed to `confirmHandler`, creates a `PaymentIntent` on the connected merchant account with the cloned `paymentMethod` and auto confirms it.

The problem is that `intentCreationCallback` expects the clientSecret to be from a `paymentIntent` created with the `payemntMethod` that `initPaymentSheet` generated and passed to `confirmHandler`, so it will resolve with an error.

Let me share the relevant code from the stripe-react-native library:

[presentPaymentSheet](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/blob/master/src/functions.ts#L419):

```js
export const presentPaymentSheet = async (
  options: PaymentSheet.PresentOptions = {}
): Promise<PresentPaymentSheetResult> => {
  try {
    const { paymentOption, error } = await NativeStripeSdk.presentPaymentSheet(
      options
    );
    if (error) {
      return {
        error,
      };
    }
    return {
      paymentOption: paymentOption!,
    };
  } catch (error: any) {
    return {
      error,
    };
  }
};
```

[initPaymentSheet](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/blob/master/src/functions.ts#L360):

```js
export const initPaymentSheet = async (
  params: PaymentSheet.SetupParams
): Promise<InitPaymentSheetResult> => {
  let result;
  const confirmHandler = params?.intentConfiguration?.confirmHandler;
  if (confirmHandler) {
    confirmHandlerCallback?.remove();
    confirmHandlerCallback = eventEmitter.addListener(
      'onConfirmHandlerCallback',
      ({
        paymentMethod,
        shouldSavePaymentMethod,
      }: {
        paymentMethod: PaymentMethod.Result;
        shouldSavePaymentMethod: boolean;
      }) => {
        confirmHandler(
          paymentMethod,
          shouldSavePaymentMethod,
          NativeStripeSdk.intentCreationCallback
        );
      }
    );
  }

  const orderTrackingCallback = params?.applePay?.setOrderTracking;
  if (orderTrackingCallback) {
    orderTrackingCallbackListener?.remove();
    orderTrackingCallbackListener = eventEmitter.addListener(
      'onOrderTrackingCallback',
      () => {
        orderTrackingCallback(NativeStripeSdk.configureOrderTracking);
      }
    );
  }

  try {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios' && !params.returnURL) {
      console.warn(
        `[@stripe/stripe-react-native] You have not provided the 'returnURL' field to 'initPaymentSheet', so payment methods that require redirects will not be shown in your iOS Payment Sheet. Visit https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=react-native&ui=payment-sheet#react-native-set-up-return-url to learn more.`
      );
    }
    result = await NativeStripeSdk.initPaymentSheet(params);

    if (result.error) {
      return {
        error: result.error,
      };
    }
    return {
      paymentOption: result.paymentOption,
    };
  } catch (error: any) {
    return {
      error,
    };
  }
};
```

[intentCreationCallback](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/blob/master/ios/StripeSdk.swift#L131C11-L131C33) (in the case of ios):

```js
    @objc(intentCreationCallback:resolver:rejecter:)
    func intentCreationCallback(result: NSDictionary, resolver resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock,
                          rejecter reject: @escaping RCTPromiseRejectBlock) -> Void  {
        guard let paymentSheetIntentCreationCallback = self.paymentSheetIntentCreationCallback else {
            resolve(Errors.createError(ErrorType.Failed, "No intent creation callback was set"))
            return
        }
        if let clientSecret = result["clientSecret"] as? String {
            paymentSheetIntentCreationCallback(.success(clientSecret))
        } else {
            class ConfirmationError: Error, LocalizedError {
                private var errorMessage: String
                init(errorMessage: String) {
                    self.errorMessage = errorMessage
                }
                public var errorDescription: String? {
                    return errorMessage
                }
            }
            let errorParams = result["error"] as? NSDictionary
            let error = ConfirmationError.init(errorMessage: errorParams?["localizedMessage"] as? String ?? "An unknown error occurred.")
            paymentSheetIntentCreationCallback(.failure(error))
        }
    }
```

I believe these are the functions that handle the call and await the response from the Stripe server.

So I create a new payment intent using the cloned payment method.
This will return either a `client_secret` if it succeeded, or error when it fails.
`intentCreationCallback` expects `result` (the result of a payment intent), which is of type `PaymentSheet.IntentCreationCallbackParams`. `result` expects either `clientSecret` or `error` which is of type `IntentCreationError`.

My intent is to only override the success part and not the error handling. We can pass the errors to `intentCreationCallback` if any exist and let the payment sheet do its thing.

It would be best if this can be achieved with edits to only the JS and not native ios/android code.

Comment: `intentCreationCallback` is meant to check the intent status and show payment outcome accordingly. How would you handle if the payment is failed? Could you elaborate more why you would like to override `intentCreationCallback` and return success automatically?

Comment: Good point. `intentCreationCallback` expects `result`, which is of type `PaymentSheet.IntentCreationCallbackParams` which is either `clientSecret` or `error` which is of type `IntentCreationError`. My intent is to override the success part and not the error handling. We can get errors on the payment intent that runs on the graphql server and pass those to `intentCreationCallback` if any exist.

Comment: Hi Ben, I'm trying to add Stripe to my React Native app too and when I'm calling initPaymentSheet(), I have to provide either paymentIntentClientSecret or setupIntentClientSecret in the arguments. How are you not using a clientSecret for your initPaymentSheet() function?

Comment: Katharsin, instead of passing those, you can pass `intentConfiguration`. See https://stripe.dev/stripe-react-native/api-reference/modules/PaymentSheet.html#IntentConfiguration

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest a workaround for handling this scenario, although, I believe it could be a nice addition to the library to have more control over `intentCreationCallback`.
The solution in this case would be to add `custom: true` to `initPaymentSheet`, fetch the PM via `confirmHandler`, clone the PM on the server, and create a PI with `confirm: true`.
I could not find a way to override the `intentCreationCallback`.